# Apache Spark isEmpty false but collection is empty

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am experiencing problems with Apache Spark when I call `isEmpty` on JavaRDD collection it returns false even though collection is empty.

Here's sample code (modified as it's from my final year project and I'm not allowed to publish any code):

```
sampleRdd = inputRdd.filter(someFilterFunction)
if(sampleRdd.isEmpty()) {
       return inputRdd.first();
} else {
        return sampleRdd.first(); // JVM points error on this line
}
```

Problem is sometimes condition is false so `sampleRdd.isEmpty()` returns false meaning it's not empty therefore execution proceeds to return statement where it's trying to retrieve `first()` element of that collection but it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1314)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1311)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.first(JavaRDDLike.scala:510)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.first(JavaRDDLike.scala:47)
.
.
.
```

Is there a bit I am missing? I'm currently running it on local machine as it's still not fully developed.

Thanks

EDIT: To add more info JVM points to line `sampleRdd.first()` when I get this error so initial inputRdd is not empty

EDIT2: I wrote some extra lines that print size of `inputRDD` before filter and `sampleRDD` after filter like that:

```
System.out.println(inputRdd.count());  // Returns nonzero possitive int eg.100
sampleRdd = inputRdd.filter(someFilterFunction)
System.out.println(sampleRdd.count()); // Returns int eg. 1 
System.out.println(sampleRdd.count()); // Sometimes returns different int than first call eg.3
if(sampleRdd.isEmpty()) {
       return inputRdd.first();
} else {
        return sampleRdd.first(); // JVM points error on this line
}
```

And I observed very interesting behaviour and that is that sometimes `inputRdd.count()` returns `100` but first `sampleRdd.count()` returns `1` and second `sampleRdd.count()` returns `3` or basically different number from the first call. So basically looks like size of `sampleRdd` changes between two calls and therefore I assume sometimes it might change to after passing condition and trying to call `first()` returns error.

Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can put println to be sure that it fails in 'sampleRdd.first()' line and you can also use count() method to see what it will return.

Comment: Yeah I already did that and sometimes count() returned number >0 and it still failed on retrieving element from sampleRdd. Issues here I guess is that it's not evaluating it sequentially or that it evaluates isEmpty before filter finishes or something

Comment: Maybe you could also do  sampleRdd.collect.get(0)? (I know that it is not the same)

Comment: I was doing that before and collect() returned empty list so I was getting index out of bounds error when I tried to access element 0

Comment: sampleRdd.isEmpty returns false, sampleRdd.count return >0. but sampleRdd.collect return an empty collection? am i right? Is there a way that you modified inputRdd after you did filter? and one more. could you do for example sampleRdd.count two times in a row(maybe it dissapers after first call)?

Comment: Yes you understand right. It is weird behaviour. Things is I call count and isEmpty after filter. I'm very confused but I'll try multiple count() calls to see if I get some inconsistent results

Comment: I added print statements checking size of the input and output RDD from filter function and I observed that I called `count()` on the output RDD and it changes size between two `count()` calls. Very strange behaviour

Comment: I almost sure that an error is out of the code you wrote here. How did you create your 'inputRdd'? Is 'someFilterFunction' deterministic?

Comment: I'm not sure cause temporarily (maybe permanently) I sorted it out by first collecting `sampleRdd.collect()` and then checking the size of List returned to driver. It's very inefficient if we consider that collecting huge input is expensive but I'm not expecting RDD from that filter to be too big so for now it's workaround.

Answer (score 1):

What if `inputRdd` is originally empty?

In that case, `sampleRdd` is also empty. Therefore `samplerdd.isEmpty` evaluates to `true` and `inputRdd.first()` throws the Exception.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to point out that error is on line where sampleRdd.first() is being called (at least that's where JVM points to)

Comment: Just to clarify by empty `inputRdd` do you mean it has no elements or that elements are all `null`? Cause I tried to `count()` before executing filter and I got positive non-zero count so definitely there are elements in `inputRdd`